# React Router: As soon as iam adding content to Route its not rendering anything anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling with a problem i cant seem to find an answer to.
As soon as I am adding a div or any other Component inside the Route it is not rendering the the content and the  containing "Application" anymore. I hope I described my Problem enough and you guys know an easy solution.

```
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (  
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Application</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/dashboard">
            <div>hi dashboard</div>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/preferences">
            <div>hi preferences</div>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you were using v5 this would work but Im assuming you are using v6 which has done a change to what @shidoro answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route` component expects an `element` prop.

Try this

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<div>hi dashboard</div>} />
    <Route path="/preferences" element={<div>hi preferences</div>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```